# if/else in foreach keep sending mail

Tags: php, foreach

I have a little if/else statement in a foreach but when the form is OK th email gets send 7 times because of the foreach..

How can I check every form but send the mail just once?

here is the code:

```
foreach($required as $field) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        echo'<script>alert("vul a.u.b. het complete formulier in")</script>';
        die(); 
    } else {
        mail($settings['email'], 'Donateur formulier website', $contents_mail, $headers);
        header("Location: ".$urlClass->buildUrl(38));
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a flag variable:

```
$flagSendMail = true;

foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $flagSendMail = false;
  } 
}

if($flagSendMail){
  //Can send
  mail($settings['email'], 'Donateur formulier website', $contents_mail, $headers);
  header("Location: ".$urlClass->buildUrl(38));
} else {
   //Validation handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great and I will remember this in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
foreach($required as $field) {
    if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        echo'<script>alert("vul a.u.b. het complete formulier in")</script>';
        die(); 
    }
}

mail($settings['email'], 'Donateur formulier website', $contents_mail, $headers);
header("Location: ".$urlClass->buildUrl(38));
```

Because if there is a required field that isn't filled in, the `die` function will stop anything after that from being run. So `mail` wont get run unless all fields are filled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used the solution of Daan but I'm sure this works as well

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach($required as $field) {
      if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
        echo'<script>alert("vul a.u.b. het complete formulier in")</script>';
        die(); 
      } else {
        header("Location: ".$urlClass->buildUrl(38));
      }
    }
    mail($settings['email'], 'Donateur formulier website', $contents_mail, $headers);
```

explanation is because it wont reach mail if the script dies anyways

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used the solution of Daan but I'm sure this works as well